# modelEvents() not getting called

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Using MarionetteJS, for some reason modelEvents() is not getting called:

```
export class MyView extends Marionette.ItemView<MyModel> {

    constructor(public model: MyModel) {
        super();
    }

    public events(): Backbone.EventsHash {
        // This gets called by the framework
        const events: Backbone.EventsHash = {};
        return events;
    }

    public modelEvents() {
        // This does not
       return {};
    }
}
```

I'm using TypeScript, and the model is passed into the constructor with a dependency injection framework (aurelia-dependency-injection).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass a model to the super constructor, so your model is being lost. Try:

```
 constructor(public model: MyModel) {
    super(model);
}
```